# CRUD com Javascript

Tags: javascript, crud

Bom, preciso fazer um *CRUD* e depois uma busca no que for submetido no meu formulário.

Já criei a página e já consigo submeter meu formulário e mostrar em uma tabela.

Duvida: **estou na duvida de como remover e alterar meu objeto já submetido.**

```js
var contatos = [ 
  document.querySelector("#campo-nome"),
  document.querySelector("#campo-endereco"),
  document.querySelector("#campo-bairro"),
  document.querySelector("#campo-telefoneFixo"),
  document.querySelector("#campo-celular"),
];
//console.log(contatos);
  
document.querySelector('#formulario').addEventListener("submit", function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

  var tr = document.createElement('tr');

  /*campo é o meu elemento, como se fosse o i.*/
  contatos.forEach(function(posicao) {
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = posicao.value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });

  var tabela = document.querySelector("table tbody");

  tabela.appendChild(tr);

  for(var i=0;i <=contatos.length;i++){
    this[i].value ='';
  }

  contatos[0].focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Agenda Contatos</h1>
  </div>
</header>
<main class="container">
  <section>
    <h2>Meus Contatos</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Rua</th>
        <th>Bairro</th>
        <th>Telefone Fixo</th>
        <th>Telefone Celular</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody class="contato">
        
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Cadastro de Contatos</h2>
    <form id="formulario" >
      <fieldset>
        <label for="campo-nome">Nome:</label>
        <input id="campo-nome" type="text" placeholder="digite o nome do seu Contato">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="campo-endereco">
        <label for="campo-endereco">Rua:</label>
        <input id="campo-endereco" type="text" placeholder="digite o endereço do seu Contato">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="campo-bairro">
        <label for="campo-bairro">Bairro:</label>
        <input id="campo-bairro" type="text" placeholder="digite o seu bairro do seu Contato">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="campo-endereco">
        <label for="campo-telefoneFixo">Telefone Fixo:</label>
        <input id="campo-telefoneFixo" type="text" placeholder="digite o telefone Fixo">
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="campo-TelefoneCelular">
        <label for="campo-celular">Telefone Celular:</label>
        <input id="campo-celular" type="text" placeholder="digite o telefone Celular">
      </fieldset>
      <button id="adicionar-contato" class="botao bto-principal">Adicionar</button>
    </form>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Se a edição que fiz não corresponder ao que pretendia perguntar, por favor reverta-a ou diga que eu faço.

Answer (score 1):

Para remover e alterar você fará o mesmo processo passando o ID.

**Remover**

Para remover, bem simples, voce vai clicar no registro da tabela que voce clicou, e enviar o ID selecionado. Dessa forma voce faz um delete passando o ID.

**Update**

O update é como voce fez no create. Porem voce vai enviar o ID. Ai no caso, voce faz um update passando o ID também que vai enviar, e altera os campos.